# Monitor network usage of a process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, network-monitoring

This question might sound fairly repetitive, but there are subtle details which make it a bit different.

I am looking for a simple tool (for Ubunut/Linux) to monitor network usage such that it gives the min, max, average, and time-plot of network usage by 1) a single process; and, 2) the system; only during the time when the process was running. The major requirement is that I am not looking for a GUI (or terminal GUI like top) based tool but I want this monitoring information to be pushed to a file so that I can perform some post-processing over that.

I come across the following link which lists various options: http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/. However, most tools are GUI based and ones which are not do not provide above information.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify why non-GUI is a requirement?  As long as the logging is non-GUI, would it be acceptable to have the stats you asked for all calculated in post-processing by a GUI app (optionally on another machine)?

Comment: I will be running few processes multiple times using a script. Every time the script invokes the process, I do not want to physically sit and monitor the network usage to report the monitoring data. Hence, I am looking for something that can be pushed to a file so that I can later post-process it.

Comment: Note that the output of `dstat -nt` can be pushed to a file from which I can calculate min/max/average/etc. However, the delay is 1 sec and I am looking for something with milliseconds granularity.

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark might work, depending on how far you're willing to relax the non-GUI requirement and whether locating your target processes is simple.  Wireshark is of course a GUI app, but the `tshark` command which comes with it is headless and can be used to capture packets to a file.  After capturing all packets on an interface, you can run `tshark` again on the pcap file to filter the file using Wireshark "Display filters" and extract just the packets for your process.  That's one part that may or may not be simple, depending on whether you can identify your process from network traffic content, port(s), or by adding some sentinel dummy data.  You'll then have two pcap files, one for the whole network interface and one for just your process.

The `capinfos` command will report the average throughput.  Wireshark can be used to generate a time-plot of the traffic with millisecond (or other) granularity via the menu "Statistics >> IO Graph".  As for min and max, you can either eyeball that from the time-plot or use `editcap` to split the pcap files into chunks, run `capinfos` on each chunk, and calculate the min and max over all chunks.

That might not be the simplest approach, it's just what occurred to me off the top of my head.

Comment: There should be an easy way to do this? I would be surprised if I have to do this tedious procedure.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a small demo about tshark, like `tshark` on `wget google.com`. Moved the point to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524246/how-to-monitor-a-single-process-with-tshark).